# How to get values of row after edit for MUI data grid?

Tags: datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to get the values thatI just edited from mui data-grid. My use case is that i would like to be able to take these values and update the state/send a request to update a database.

I have tried using **onEditRowsModelChange** and **onRowEditStop** properties but **onEditRowsModelChange** updates too frequently for my needs and **onRowEditStop** returns the previous values but not the most recent updated ones. The values are also in a form that is requires parsing to get to.

has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 11):

With default edit mode (cell edit mode)
you have to use the `onCellEditCommit`

```
const onCellEditCommit= (cellData) => {
    const { id, field, value } = cellData;
    ...
}


<DataGrid 
    onCellEditCommit={onCellEditCommit}
    ...
```

With row edit mode, you can use the `processRowUpdate` but make sure you're using `experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}` with the datagrid

```
const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    ...
    return updatedRow;
};


<DataGrid 
    editMode="row"
    processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
    experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
    ...
```

Comment: Could you precise that the first solution including onCellEditCommit ll work only in legacy legacy editing api: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing-legacy/#events 

and you shouldn't put : 

experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}

Answer (score 5):

You can use OnCellEditCommit

```
<DataGridPro
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    onCellEditCommit={handleRowEditCommit}
/>
```

your handleRowEditCommit function will look like this

```
    const handleRowEditCommit = React.useCallback(
        (params) => {
            const id = params.id;
            const key = params.field;
            const value = params.value; },
        []
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the details of committed row using `apiRef`.

I have managed this situation like below:

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
    
const onRowEditCommit = (id, event) => {
     let row = apiRef.current.getEditRowsModel();
     handleRowEdit(row);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This only works on the pro version.

Comment: getRowModels doesn't need pro - see : https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-api/

Answer (score 2):

A litter late but.

You are looking for processRowUpdate, it received two params, newRow, and oldRow.

```
const handleProcessRowUpdate = (newRow, oldRow) => {
    //Here manipulate the rows depending on what you want to do
}

<DataGrid 
    processRowUpdate={handleProcessRowUpdate}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `processRowUpdate` prop mentioned in the DataGrid API documentation.

Below, I created a function to update the rows that looks up by its index and then updates it. You can use it to update your data.

Here is the link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/save-data-grid-rows-in-state-pcjd5j?file=/demo.js:1616-2465).

```
const handleProcessRowUpdate = (updatedRow, originalRow) => {
  // Find the index of the row that was edited
  const rowIndex = rows.findIndex((row) => row.id === updatedRow.id);

  // Replace the old row with the updated row
  const updatedRows = [...rows];
  updatedRows[rowIndex] = updatedRow;

  // Update the state with the new rows
  setRows(updatedRows);

  // Return the updated row to update the internal state of the DataGrid
  return updatedRow;
};

return (
  <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      initialState={{
        pagination: {
          paginationModel: {
            pageSize: 5
          }
        }
      }}
      processRowUpdate={handleProcessRowUpdate}
      pageSizeOptions={[5]}
      checkboxSelection
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
    />
  </Box>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, brother.
and use this for track your errors onProcessRowUpdateError={(e) => console.log(e)}

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather ugly solution using the onEditRowsModelChange method.
It does some debouncing and parsing as you mentioned:

```js
let timer;
const handleEditRowsModelChange = (model) => {
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setEditRowsModel(model);
            let siteId = Object.keys(model)[0];
            let field = siteId ? Object.keys(model[siteId])[0] : null;
            let value = field ? model[siteId][field].value : null;
            siteId && field && (
                sites.forEach(site => {
                    if (site.id == siteId) { 
                        if (site[field] != value) {
                            site[field] = value;
                            sendSiteForEdit(site);
                        }
                    };
                }
            ));
        }, 1500);
};
```